# In TeamCity Professional 10.0.4 (build 42538) Pending Changes are not clearing after build

Tags: teamcity

I've trying seeing in similar posts if someone has had this issue but it was not clear to me, so here it goes.

We have a project, that whenever we run it, we don't get the Pending Changes reset. I see in the table below that the changes actually change through time, but there is no update on the tab as I show below.

[image]

Any Clue on this? Version is TeamCity Professional 10.0.4 (build 42538)

Comment: Have you built all the branches?

Comment: I've had a similar problem, described and discussed with JetBrains [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-49005).

Comment: I really don't know if it is the same, also I'm quite recent in terms of TeamCity :) what I notice is that this happens when I have the default branch selected. When I change to other branch it shows less info. For the default branch I see changes since 2015...

Comment: Well, for Active Branches and Default Branch. If I choose another branch I get 3 pending changes... which is right.